# wordpress submit for review instead of publish

Tags: mysql, wordpress

After I upgrade my mysql 5.1 to 5.7, my wordpress can not publish any post.

The publish button is replaced by "submit for review".

I tried

1. repair database table
2. auto increment
3. Plugin confliction
4. repair wp admin account

No one works.

I think it is the confict about mysql version. Anyone can help me?

ps: In phpmyadmin, i can see that my mysql client version is still 5.1 . Does it matters?

---

The problem is solved.

It caused by mysql 5.7 sql_mode. In mysql 5.7, sql_mode is strict than wordpress sql code. In mysql 5.7, sql_mode is:
ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

just remove STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO

Comment: Are you still a full-admin? Go to user settings and try to refresh the role by re-saving if so.

Comment: @WPZA, I tries this way, it didn't work for me.

Comment: have you set ID in the wp-post table as primary key?